# How to preload Image.network

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I get different imageURLs from Firestore multiple times and display them on the screen, but it feels a little slow to load. So I want to preaload the image, is there a way?

Specifically, in the following code, when counter == 0, I want to read the imageURL when counter == 1, 2. (Flutter will then cache the image, so when the counter reaches 1 or 2, the image will load faster.)

I also tried CachedImageNetwork but didn't know how to adapt it to this case

```
class TestScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestScreenState createState() => _TestScreenState();
}

class _TestScreenState extends State<TestScreen> {

  int counter=0;
  List imageURLList=['url1','url2','url3'];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Image.network(imageURLList[counter]),
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: (){
                setState(() {
                  counter++;
                });
              },
              child: Text('push'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: for the caching image , you can use https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to load your network image even when they are not displayed.
**EDIT after testing:** Instead of using a List of url I would use a List containing NetworkImage object and using the method `precacheImage`.

```
class _TestScreenState extends State<TestScreen> {
  int counter = 0;
  List<NetworkImage> imgList = [
    NetworkImage("url1"),
    NetworkImage("url2"),
    NetworkImage("url3"),
  ];

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    for (var img in imgList) {
      precacheImage(img, context);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Image(image: imgList[counter]),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            counter++;
          });
        },
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```